# magento 1 additional option of type file to cart programatically

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, custom-options, addtocart, development

i want to add `custom option` of file type while `product` is `adding to cart`.
like i will be giving a `customer an option`  to `choose image` from his computer, and when customer choose and hit `add to cart button` then the image should be added as custom option to that product.

anyone knows how to do it?